# Discord's new support for slash commands | AttributeError with discord-py-slash-command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Is there any official support for the new Discord slash commands; if not, how do you use the `discord-py-slash-command` module as I couldn't get that to work

I've been spending a while trying to work out how to use the new slash commands and I couldn't find Discord saying how to use it on discord.py.

After a bit of searching I've found a module called `discord-py-slash-command` but I couldn't figure out how to use this either.

When I tried to implement it into the main code of my bot nothing happened, so I tried to just run the example they showed on their website [here](https://pypi.org/project/discord-py-slash-command/) (The top example) without modifying it and that also didn't work, and return this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/224/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2167, in <module>
    main()
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/224/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2034, in main
    debugger = PyDB()
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/224/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 407, in __init__
    self._cmd_queue = defaultdict(_queue.Queue)  # Key is thread id or '*', value is Queue
AttributeError: module 'queue' has no attribute 'Queue'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here's my copy and pasted code from their example:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash import SlashCommand
from discord_slash import SlashContext

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())
slash = SlashCommand(bot)


@slash.slash(name="test")
async def _test(ctx: SlashContext):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="embed test")
    await ctx.send(content="test", embeds=[embed])




bot.run(".token.txt")
```

Comment: discord.py doesn't support slash commands, and I don't think it will ever

Comment: It will support in some point, but in my opinion, this will take long time.

Comment: Well maybe at some point, but the creator of the library is not excited about it [link](https://streamable.com/mmggcx)

Comment: The creators of the `discord.py` library have stated that it may require a whole redo/remake of the entire package. This will take a LONG time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very qualified with `discord-py-slash-command` but as far as I know, you have to pass some arguments in `@slash.slash()` such as `description` etc.

```py
guild_ids = [<your guild id>]
slash = SlashCommand(bot, auto_register=True)
@slash.slash(
    name="ttest",
    description="Sends message.",
    guild_ids=guild_ids
)
async def _test(ctx: SlashContext):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="embed test")
    await ctx.send(content='test', embeds=[embed])
```

This will work but I don't recommend you to use this module until it's references became more clear. It's so unclear and unhandy also it's syntax is so complicated compared to `discord.py`.

Also, you have to enable `applications.commands` scope from [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) -> OAuth2 -> Scopes.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently been building a bot with discord-py-slash-command. I've figured out that the best way to make a command would be to read their documentation (below).

With your command, what I notice first that I haven't used is `ctx: SlashContext`, instead, try using just `ctx`. Your script is also probably you used `Embeds=[embed]`, and I am not sure how multiple embeds would work, but for a single one, `embed=` is lowercase. I'm pretty sure you don't need the `content=''`.

The errors seems to be coming from pycharm and not the script itself, maybe try another IDE.

Documentation:
https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Option Types (I found this really useful):
https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/latest/discord_slash.model.html?highlight=USER#discord_slash.model.SlashCommandOptionType.USER

My discord is `_stefthedoggo#1698`, DM me if you want more help, I have a working bot running solely on discord-py-slash-commands